# Defacto standard C++11 coding style?

Tags: c++

Is there a defacto standard coding style for C++11? I'm starting to work on a small project and i'm very used to the C# standard: class names, namespaces, methods and properties with PascalCasing. Does C++ use camelCase instead?

Comment: Nope. Unlike C# and more especially Java there isn't any specialization of coding style for C++.  It varies widely between projects.  Pick one and stick w/it.

Comment: A coding style is much more than a naming convention. Are you interested in full coding standards or only in naming conventions?

Comment: @stefan The question is not asking which coding standard to use or which is *the* C++ coding standard. It's asking whether one prevailing style exists. I'd say that as such, it has a clear non-opinion-based answer: "no."

Comment: There is no "standard" C++ coding style, but the examples in the ISO C++ standard do tend to follow a reasonably consistent style. Consistency is far more important than the choice of any one style over another, but if you're in a position to pick your own style, IMHO using the same one used by the standard (and, I believe, in Stroustrup's books) is a reasonable choice.

Comment: @stefan, "Your Favourite Coding Standard Sucks"

Comment: Opinion.  I prefer CamelCase to snake case, and please don't mention Pascal in mixed company :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does C++ use camelCase instead?

There is no single standard style in the C++ world.  There are quite a few common styles, but not a single style that exists everywhere.  In general, the best you can hope for is consistency in your own group, and that each library you use stays consistent within itself.

PascalCase is rare in C++ libraries.  camelCase is more common, but it's also very common to have underscore_separated naming.  The latter is probably the most common, since the C++ Standard Library uses underscore_separation in naming.

Answer (score 8):

The only C++ style I know of that it not entirely dependent on the dev culture working on the project is consistency. Whatever you do, do it consistently.

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the day, it depends on the team you work with and the company requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Do as this guy does and you won't be far wrong:

1. Bjarne Stroustrup, "A Tour of C++", Addison-Wesley, 2013.
2. Bjarne Stroustrup, "The C++ Programming Language", 4 ed., Addison-Wesley, 2013.
3. Bjarne Stroustrup, "Programming: Principles and Practice Using C++", Addison-Wesley, 2008.